# Connection to SQL Express using Integrated Security Failing on Amazon EC2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a t2-micro instance of Windows Server 2019 on Amazon EC2.I have installed SQL Server and IIS for Web Development.
I have deployed a `asmx` web service using the zip package.I have manually created the database using SSMS.
Using the following connection string results in an error

```
 static string Source = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=coredatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

SSMS works fine with this connection
[image]

I get the following error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database &quot;coredatabase&quot; requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user &#39;IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool&#39;.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at SIT_Service.CoreService.checkifuserexistsinternal(String email, String mainauthtoken) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Web Service\Web Service (1)\Web Service\WebApplication2\CoreService.asmx.cs:line 429
   at SIT_Service.CoreService.register(String email, String password, String mainauthtoken) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Web Service\Web Service (1)\Web Service\WebApplication2\CoreService.asmx.cs:line 498
```

Comment: Have a look at the SQL logs, what is the actual error for the connection failure in there?

Comment: @Larnu `Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'coredatabase'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]`

Comment: Does the `LOGIN` (`IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`) have a mapped `USER` for the database `coredatabase`?

Comment: @Larnu No. I have done that as per the answer below.It fixed the issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says: "Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool", which means that the login failed for the user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool.

Probably because that Windows user doesn't have a SQL Server login.  In SSMS connect to your database in a query window and run

```
use coredatabase
create login [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] from windows;
create user [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] for login [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool];
grant select, insert, update, delete to [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool];  --or whatever
```

Comment: The Sql server log says `Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'coredatabase'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]`